# Best way to use jquery rails to save an api callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, balanced-payments

I'm trying to understand [this payment api,](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api) particularly their create bank account form. It is posting bank account info to their servers and then passing back a callback. Question is how do I catch this call back and add it to my user model.

[This is their jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/alaingoldman/cpxLp/6/)

Here is a part of their javascript:

```
    case 201:  / This is what happens when bank account is correct
        var $form = $("#bank-account-form");
        var bank_account_uri = response.data['uri'];
        $('<input>').attr({
           type: 'hidden',
           value: bank_account_uri,
           name: 'balancedBankAccountURI'
        }).appendTo($form);
        $form.attr({action: requestBinURL});
        $form.get(0).submit(); }}
```

This is the case when the bank account is correct. And it's creating the hidden input and submitting the form but I have no idea how to replicate that in my rails app.

I have to add it to the User table customer_uri column. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried sending a put/patch request via `$.ajax` in the success callback to a route where you can update the user model with the data from said request?

Comment: I'm super noob i wouldn't even know what that looks like

Answer (score 1):

As we discussed in #balanced on IRC, here's a rough example on how to accomplish what you're looking for. https://gist.github.com/remear/7f6d7e6f24aa7e63fd2b

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.